# Deserializing immutable record arrays using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, system.text.json

Let say we have theese records:

```
public record ResponseFake
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public ResponseFake(OhlcFake[] quotes)
    {
        Quotes = quotes;
    }
   public OhlcFake[] Quotes { get; }
}
public record OhlcFake
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public OhlcFake(QuoteFake o)
    {
        O = o;
    }
    public QuoteFake O { get; }
}
public record QuoteFake
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public QuoteFake(decimal bid)
    {
        Bid = bid;
    }
    public decimal Bid { get; }
}
```

And this XUnit test:

```
[Fact]
public void QuoteChartResponseFakeDeserializationTest()
{
    var data = @"{""quotes"": [ { ""o"": { ""bid"": 1.1 } } ] }";

    var result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseFake>(data);

    result.Quotes.Should().NotBeEmpty();
}
```

Test fail with error "Expected result.Quotes not to be empty, but found ."

What should I do to get `Quotes` populated?

Comment: Add `[JsonConstructor]` to all your ctors

Comment: I does not help...

Comment: Your json is camelcase, the serializer out of the box won't deserialize camelcase, you will have to add `JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase`

Answer (score 8):

The solution is adding `JsonSerializerOptions` with `PropertyNamingPolicy`.

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
};
var result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseFake>(data, options);
```

Comment: Side note: you want to reuse `JsonSerializerOptions`, since it will cache serialization metadata. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-configure-options).